# MySQL error 1054 (42S22) when using UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

When using the MySQL command line interface, I enter the following command:

```
UPDATE movies SET Title=Full WHERE ID=6;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Full' in 'field list'
```

I have verified that I am using the table 'movies' and the column 'Title' exist.  Also, there does indeed exist an entry with an ID=6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Full is not quoted, so it's being treated as if it were a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE movies SET Title="Full" WHERE ID=6;` ???

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!  Does that have to be done for every field I change?